# Why is the JavaScript prompt box too small?

Tags: javascript

When I call window.prompt() in javascript and the first parameter (the message) is too large, the box doesn't get any larger. When the same thing happens with window.alert(), the box resizes accordingly. Is there some way to fix this or do I have to make my own prompt box, and if so, can I at least be pointed in the right direction of how that is done?

Comment: there is now way to control the appearance/sizing/position of those boxes. all you have are "text" and "value" as options. If the native versions aren't good enough, you'll have to roll your own.

Comment: I believe it is not possible to change these, but you can create custom div or use components like jQuery UI / Twitter Bootstrap or others to create dialog boxes.

Comment: Have a look at [Alertify.js](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/)

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to alter that behaviour. It's totally up to the browser to bring up the window.

One cannot show a native dialog (as alert() or prompt() do), instead, one has to imitate that behaviour in the space of the page's body. This would involve creating an overlay for a *modal* dialog and a simple absolutely-positioned container for the message.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a JQuery UI dialog?

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

HTML

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
<p>Text</p>

    <form>

    </form>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  height: 300,
  width: 350,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Button": function() {
        //On click
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" ); //Close dialog
    }
  }
});
```